# No authentication needed to login to my Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: ssh, terminal

If I type in `ssh <user>@<ip_address>` or `ssh root@<ip_address>`, I instantly connect to my remote server (Digital Ocean droplet). However I should be prompted for my SSH key as security before logging in. I've followed the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04#step-six-%E2%80%94-test-log-in) so I'm not sure why it doesn't ask for my SSH key before logging in. Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasons for key authentication not asking for password may be:

1. the SSH key has previously been loaded in ssh-agent. If so, the passphrase will be asked again only when you reload the ssh-agent.
2. the SSH key has been created without password. If so, you can fix this using "ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]" on id_rsa file.
3. The user has been created on your remote system without password (and sshd with PasswordAuthentication yes)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 1? I think it's that. What triggers the ssh-agent to reload? How can I change my settings so it always asks for the SSH key when I open a new terminal? PS: I tried to login on another computer and it said `Permission denied (publickey).` which is good.

Comment: There are several ways of using ssh-agent, either directly using command-line ssh-agent / ssh-add , or through possible desktop integration (e.g. ssh-askpass-gnome, ...). Using any form of ssh-agent, you'll be asked only once for password during session lifetime.